# linkedin authorization in python

Tags: python-2.7, linkedin-api

I'm new to the linkedin API. What I'm trying to do is to retrieve some job posting information and people information on LinkedIn.

I have registered on LinkedIn API page, with Auth 2.0 Redirect URLs: http://localhost:8000

I was following the instructions on http://ozgur.github.io/python-linkedin/
I was able to complete the **Authentication** step, where I was able to get the `authentication.authorization_code` and `authentication.get_access_token()` with my own key and secret. however, when i tried **Quick Usage From Python Interpreter**

```
from linkedin import server
application = server.quick_api(KEY, SECRET)
```

Then, when I copied the URL into the web browser. I was given error message :

> invalid redirect_uri. This value must match a URL registered with the
>   API Key.

I'm not sure where the problem is, may someone help me with this?
thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you read the authentication documentation available at https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication?

Comment: thanks, Justin. I have tried it. It worked well after I obtained my token and I was able to retrieve my linkedin profile page. btw, do you know how to make the whole process automatically?